# JFrame won't show - Not an error in code

Tags: java, swing

Recently every single one of my apps that extends JFrame fails to actually show the frame. The program will run and then will terminate after about 8 seconds without ever showing anything and without an error message. This happens for all the programs I've made in the past as well as any new programs.

For testing purposes I am using the basic example from the oracle documentations.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class test extends JFrame{

    public static void main(String[] args){ 
        //1. Create the frame.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("FrameDemo");

        //2. Optional: What happens when the frame closes?
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //3. Create components and put them in the frame.
        JLabel emptyLabel = new JLabel();
        frame.getContentPane().add(emptyLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        //4. Size the frame.
        frame.pack();

        //5. Show it.
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

I am using eclipse and I've already tried switching workplaces.

I've looked at existing threads and found nothing that wasn't due to coding errors.

How can i solve this?

EDIT: The program doesn't output anything from System.out.println() after this line:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("FrameDemo");
```

It outputs anything before that.

Comment: Why does test extend JFrame?

Comment: It's just a test, i have the same issue regardless if it extends jframe.

Comment: Works for me just fine.  I get small window to the top/left (compressed to the frame boundaries) corner of my screen..

Comment: Put a `System.out.println` in your `main` method and make sure it's actually been run...

Comment: Yea it use to work for me too, and now it just doesn't. #Technology It does actually run, it will output anything prior to setting up the jframe. anything after that won't show.

Answer (score 1):

Alright so I checked your code and it works.
First things first, your JLabel isn't visible if it doesn't have anything in it.

```
pack(); 
//basically CRUSHES the entire frame if it doesn't have objects to collapse on.
```

Also, if you don't want to put anything in your JLabel, don't pack it yet. Just set it to a certain size with

```
frame.setSize(width,height);
```

It only shows nothing because you collapsed it without putting anything in the JLabel. I hope I answered your question basically this is what you want

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class test extends JFrame{

    public static void main(String[] args){ 
        //1. Create the frame.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("FrameDemo");

        //2. Optional: What happens when the frame closes?
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //3. Create components and put them in the frame.
        JLabel emptyLabel = new JLabel("BLAHBLAHBHALBAHLKKDJF");
        frame.getContentPane().add(emptyLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

       //4. Size the frame.
        frame.pack();

        //5. Show it.
        frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

Or you could just set size with

```
frame.setSize(width,height);
```

Have fun!

Comment: I've copied exactly what you typed to confirm that it doesn't work, program runs and then terminates with no error after about 8 seconds. I've also reinstalled eclipse and i'm still having this problem.

Comment: @user3382192 Just a clarification on the use of the `pack()` method. This method returns the `preferredSize` and layout of its subcomponents. It is important to remember that preferred size is set when you use some sort of Layout Manager AND that the behavior of `pack()` changes according to the Layout Manager used (this is because not all Layout Managers "respect" the preferred size.)  However, if you are using Absolute Positioning (manually setting dimensions and location for all components in a container AND setting Layout Manager to NULL), you don't really need to invoke `pack()`.

Comment: I have countless programs that use jframe for games and such that are all having this problem. not everyone of them uses pack, and i can take pack out of the above program and it still doesn't work. It's not an error in code as 1 day ago they were all working. I don't know what the problem is. I've uninstalled eclipse, I've uninstalled java and reinstalled everything.